# Obtener valor de un input en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy estoy generando una lista con un `input` de tipo `button` esta lista se genera de una `bd` que tengo con 4 datos por consiguiente me genera 4 botones los cuales le he dado un identificador "`alum[i].ID_EVENTO "` que es un numero 1,2,3,4 como puedo sacar el valor de cada uno de esos botones adjunto el `html` y JavaScript

```
<body>
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

    <table class="table" >
    <tbody id="myTable">
         <tr>
            <td>ID_EVENTO</td>
            <td>NOMBRE_EVENTO</td>
            <td>FECHA</td>
             <td>RESUMEN</td>
             <td>DESCRIPCION</td>
             <td>CATEGORIA</td>
             <td>SEDE</td>
             <td>LUGAR</td>
             <td>CUPOS</td>
             <td>DURACION_HORAS</td>
             <td>FACULTAD</td>
             <td>CREDITOS</td>
             <td>Agregar</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



</body>
```

**Js**

```
  var url ='/api/api.php';
   var h;
    var listusers =$('.table');
        $.ajax({
             url: url,
             method:'GET',
             type: 'JSON'
        }).done(function (alumnos) {
           var alum = JSON.parse(alumnos);
           $.each(alum,function (i,item) {

               listusers.append('<tr ><td>'+ alum[i].ID_EVENTO + '</td>'  + '<td>'+ alum[i].NOMBRE_EVENTO + '</td>' +  '<td>' + alum[i].FECHA + '<td>'+ alum[i].RESUMEN + '</td>' + '<td>'+ alum[i].DESCRIPCION + '</td>' + '<td>'+ alum[i].CATEGORIA + '</td>' + '<td>'+ alum[i].SEDE + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ alum[i].LUGAR + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ alum[i].CUPOS + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ alum[i].DURACION_HORAS + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ alum[i].FACULTAD + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ alum[i].CREDITOS + '</td>' + "<td><input type='button' id=\"btn btn-info\" class='boton"+i+"'   value="+ alum[i].ID_EVENTO +" >  </input> </td>");;

               h=i;
           });
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás poniendo mal los parámetros de la llamada Ajax. En vez de:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method:'GET',
  type: 'JSON'
})
```

Debiera ser

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type:'GET',
  dataType: 'json'
})
```

Suponiendo que tu backend devuelve JSON tal como lo estás pidiendo, y no texto, también podrías saltarte el parseo. Pero bueno, supongamos que recibes simplemente texto del backend así que debes parsearlo. Tenemos entonces que `alum` es un array de 4 elementos, cada uno de los cuales es un objeto con llaves `ID_EVENTO`, `NOMBRE_EVENTO` etc.

Separando el append que haces a tu tabla, tenemos que en una parte pones

```
'<td>' + alum[i].FECHA + '<td>'+ alum[i].RESUMEN + '</td>'
```

Falta el tag de cierre para la celda de fecha.

Más adelante, al añadir el botón, pones:

```
"<td><input type='button' id=\"btn btn-info\" class='boton"+i+"'   value="+ alum[i].ID_EVENTO +" >  </input> </td>"
```

Estás poniéndole como ID lo que debiera ser clase, y como clase lo que debiera ser id:

```
"<td><input type='button' class=\"btn btn-info\" id='boton"+i+"'   value="+ alum[i].ID_EVENTO +" >  </input> </td>"
```

Finalmente, no estás poniendo el cierre de la fila (`</tr>`);

Para que quedase más limpio, yo declararía una variable que fuera el objeto `alum[i]` quedando:

```
var current_alum=alum[i];

listusers.append(
   '<tr>'+
   '<td>'+ current_alum.ID_EVENTO + '</td>' +
   '<td>'+ current_alum.NOMBRE_EVENTO + '</td>' +  
   '<td>'+ current_alum.FECHA + '</td>'+
   '<td>'+ current_alum.RESUMEN + '</td>' + 
   '<td>'+ current_alum.DESCRIPCION + '</td>' + 
   '<td>'+ current_alum.CATEGORIA + '</td>' + 
   '<td>'+ current_alum.SEDE + '</td>'+ 
   '<td>'+ current_alum.LUGAR + '</td>'+
   '<td>'+ current_alum.CUPOS + '</td>'+ 
   '<td>'+ current_alum.DURACION_HORAS + '</td>'+ 
   '<td>'+ current_alum.FACULTAD + '</td>'+
   '<td>'+ current_alum.CREDITOS + '</td>' + 
   '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="boton'+i+'"   value="'+ current_alum.ID_EVENTO +'" >  </input> </td>'+
   '</tr>');
```

El listener para obtener el valor del botón puedes añadirlo ahí mismo dentro del bucle

```
$('#boton'+i).on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this).val()); //obtener el valor del input
});
```

o delegarlo afuera como te mostró @Dev.Joel

```
listusers.on('click','.btn', function(){
    console.log($(this).val()); //obtener el valor del input
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me funciono

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el valor del `input` , podría añadir una **clase** global *(selection)*  . a estos elementos y así añadir el `listener` a todos. *(En su código debe reemplazar `id` por `class` para el `input`)*.

Además en el `$.each` debería emplear la variable `item` que sería equivalente a `alum[i]`

```
$(function() {
    var url ='/api/api.php';
    var listusers =$('.table');
    $.ajax({
             url: url,
             method:'GET',
             type: 'JSON'
        }).done(function (alumnos) {
           $.each(JSON.parse(alumnos),function (i,item) {
               listusers.append('<tr ><td>'+ item.ID_EVENTO + '</td>'  + '<td>'+ item.NOMBRE_EVENTO + '</td>' +  '<td>' + item.FECHA + '<td>'+ item.RESUMEN + '</td>' + '<td>'+ item.DESCRIPCION + '</td>' + '<td>'+ item.CATEGORIA + '</td>' + '<td>'+ item.SEDE + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ item.LUGAR + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ item.CUPOS + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ item.DURACION_HORAS + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ item.FACULTAD + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ item.CREDITOS + '</td>' + "<td><input type='button' class=\"btn btn-info selection\"   value="+ item.ID_EVENTO +" >  </input> </td>");;
           });
    });

    //Listener a los elementos con la clase que se añadió 
    $(document).on('click','.selection',function(){
        console.log($(this).val()); //obtener el valor del input
    });
});
```

Comment: Eso no va a funcionar. Deberías asociar la función al evento dentro de la función del `done`. Tal y como está cuando se ejecuta la instrucción para asociar el handler al evento click los botones aún no están definidos.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva sí funcionaría, el evento está delegado en `document` que sí existe

Comment: Cierto. Perdón. Por responder a la carrera :D

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo al final cada input te queda con clase "boton1", "boton2" y así...

Puedes hacer referencia a esa clase para cada botón y usas .val() para obtener el valor.

```
var valor1 = $('boton1').val();
var valor2 = $('boton2').val();
var valor3 = $('boton3').val();
var valor4 = $('boton4').val();
```

Saludos